# guestmount and write permissions

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I'm mounting VMDK disk:

```
virt-list-partitions -lh _VMDK_FILE_
/dev/sda1 ext4 121.0G
```

with following parameters:

```
guestmount -a _VMDK_FILE_ -m /dev/sda1 -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 --rw _MOUNT_PATH_
```

image is mounted correctly, I have write access, almost perfect.

My user is:

```
uid=1000(osboxes) gid=1000(osboxes) groups=1000(osboxes)
```

but when I create directory in the mounted image:

```
mkdir test
```

and I test for write permissions:

```
[ ! -w test ] && echo "no write permissions!"
```

then I get the message that I do not have write permissions!

ls shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 osboxes osboxes  4096 Jun  4 06:07 test
```

but when I add write permissions for others:

```
chmod o+w test

drwxr-xrwx   3 osboxes osboxes  4096 Jun  4 06:07 test
```

then test for write permissions shows, that I have now write permissions!

What am I missing?

I also tried mounting with sudo and allow_other:

```
sudo guestmount -a _VMDK_FILE_ -m /dev/sda1 -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o allow_other --rw _MOUNT_PATH_
```

and the same problem persists.

**SystemInfo:**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- guestfish 1.40.2
- backend: direct

Answer (score 0):

**chmod o+w** gives write permission to the Other, basically everyone else on the system, and is subsequently a very bad idea from a security perspective. It's a method of last resort / for testing purposes only when done properly. If you have not done so already, remove it with:

```
chmod o-w test
```

Your user (first column in octal permissions) has write permissions but not your group. Try running the following and then trying again:

```
chmod g+w test
```

Comment: OK, tried it and still NOK.

ls shows:
drwxrwxr-x   3 osboxes osboxes 

but test for write permissions still says that I do NOT have write permissions.